# Problema con el contador de un ciclo for

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Buen dia, espero me puedan ayudar, con lo siguiente:

> ```
> public void llenarTrancisiones1() {
>     automata1 = new Transiciones[estadosMaquina1.length * alfabeto.length];
>     for (int i = 0; i < estadosMaquina1.length; i++) {
>         for (int j = 0; j < alfabeto.length; j++) {
>             String fin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "¿El estado " + estadosMaquina1[i].getNombre()
>                     + " con el simbolo " + alfabeto[j] + " a que estado q va a pasar?");
>             automata1[i] = new Transiciones(estadosMaquina1[i], alfabeto[j], estadosMaquina1[Integer.parseInt(fin)]);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

tengo el anterior for necesito que el contador i se mantenga por dos veces en el mismo numero es decir tener lo siguiente:

estadosMaquina1[0], alfabeto[0]

estadosMaquina1[0], alfabeto[1]

estadosMaquina1[1], alfabeto[0]

estadosMaquina1[1], alfabeto[1]

no se como hacerlo, espero me puedan ayudar se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Lo estás haciendo bien. Lo que no está bien es la asignación que haces en `automata1[i]`; eso hará que reasignes un nuevo objeto `Transiciones` en el mismo campo por cada `j`, hasta que pasa al siguiente `i`. Si lo cambias por `automata1[i * alfabeto.length + j]` podría funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias soluciono mi problema excelente respuesta

Comment: @GlennSandoval considera agregar una respuesta a la pregunta en vez del comentario, asi otras personas pueden encontrar fácilmente la solución

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema se soluciono con lo siguiente:

```
automata1[i * alfabeto.length + j] = new Transiciones(estadosMaquina1[i], alfabeto[j], estadosMaquina1[Integer.parseInt(fin)]);
```